# Set class with timed auto remove of elements

Tags: python

I'm writing a software with Python and I need a class to store a set of elements (order is not relevant and not repeated elements), like the Python class `set`, but I need that the elements are auto-removed after a period of time.

For that, I want to overwrite the `set.add` method, adding an argument with default value with this timeout.

My problem is with the best way to implement that: threads? gobject-like timeouts?

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just an idea (of course, it isn't the best one): Use a dictionary to store the timestamp of each addition plus the concrete timeout for each item. Then, when you want to check if an item is in the set, you have to compare the current time with the value in the dictionary. This way you don't need to start a new thread to remove each item when the timeout is finished (just keep the key in the dictionary, and update it if the item is added again).

With this solution you have to implement `__contains__` and `__iter__` apart from `add`, to make sure `'a' in myset` and `iter(myset)` returns consistent results.

```
import time

class TimedSet(set):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__table = {}
    def add(self, item, timeout=1):
        self.__table[item] = time.time() + timeout
        set.add(self, item)
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return time.time() < self.__table.get(item)
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in set.__iter__(self):
            if time.time() < self.__table.get(item):
                yield item
```

And a possible example of usage:

```
t_set = TimedSet()
t_set.add('a')
time.sleep(0.6)
print 'a' in t_set
time.sleep(0.6)
print 'a' in t_set

t_set.add('x', 0.3)
t_set.add('y', 0.4)
t_set.add('z', 0.5)
time.sleep(0.35)
for item in t_set:
    print item
```

Comment: I like very much your idea. It is simple and I have a nice way to control the size of the cache. Thank you very much

Comment: Beware: This will give wrong value for `len()` You may want to implement `__len__()` as well

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason not to go with multithreading. As it is really easy to implement, with minimum code. Roughly something like this:

```
import threading
import time

def ttl_set_remove(my_set, item, ttl):
    time.sleep(ttl)
    my_set.remove(item)

class MySet(set):
    def add(self, item, ttl):
        set.add(self, item)
        t = threading.Thread(target=ttl_set_remove, args=(self, item, ttl))
        t.start()
```

test:

```
s = MySet()
s.add('a', 20)
s.add('b', 10)
s.add('c', 2)

print(s)
time.sleep(5)
print(s)

>>> 
MySet({'c', 'b', 'a'})
MySet({'b', 'a'})
```

Comment: It is a good approach, but it has two main cons for me: first, it uses threads, which is not bad itself, but used with the libraries I'm already using can be dangerous. The second one is: how can you control if a element is added again? I will need to cancel its timeout-thread or reseting it in some way. I would need to store the thread object for each element inside my set and "kill" the thread before it deletes my element! Anyway, thank you for your response :-)